# How to get a confirmation or callback from angularjs-rails-resource on create(), update()

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm using [AngularJs Rails Resouce](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource) and was wondering if there was a callback for when you successfully create/update a resource using the `create()` or `update()` methods.

For instance, here's my code:

```
$scope.createPage = function () {
    var page = new Page({
        title: $scope.pageTitle,
        content: $scope.pageContent,
        published: true
    });
    if (page.create()){
        $scope.showAlert('Page created successfully', 'success');
    } else {
        $scope.showAlert('There was a problem creating the page.', 'warning');
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work. Even if the API is not available, the success message is created.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the promise look at [Using resources](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource#using-resources):

```
$scope.createPage = function () {
    var page = new Page({
        title: $scope.pageTitle,
        content: $scope.pageContent,
        published: true
    });

    page.create().then(function (results) {
        console.log(results);
        $scope.showAlert('Page created successfully', 'success');
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        $scope.showAlert('There was a problem creating the page.', 'warning');
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for.